# Programmatically setting the name of a variable

Tags: javascript

Is there a shortcut for writing the following 100 assignments?

```
variable_1 = 1;
variable_2 = 2;
variable_3 = 3;

...

variable_100 = 100;
```

I have tried

```
for(var i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
    variable_ + i = i;
}
```

but I get the error message "Invalid left-hand side in assignment". Any ideas?

Comment: Why not use an array?  https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Here are a few methods:

### Method 1: use eval

Here is the most direct method:

```
for(var i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
  eval("var variable_" + i + " = " + i);
}
variable_1; // => 1
```

**Disclaimer for the above method**: I don't think this problem is a good candidate for using `eval`. If you *do* use `eval`, you should never allow user input to go into what you are `eval`ing, or you could open your site to security risks. That mistake is the main reason people say `eval` is evil.

### Method 2: use dynamically generated object properties

This is a *much, much* better way:

```
// If you want these variables to be global, then use `window` (if you're 
// in a browser) instead of your own object.
var obj = {};
for(var i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
  obj["variable_" + i] = i;
}
obj.variable_1; // => 1
```

About the note in the comment about using window to create global variables: I would recommend against this, as it is a quick way to pollute your global scope and step on variables unwittingly.

### Method 3: use an array

David suggested using an array. This is another great idea, and, depending on what you are trying to do, may be preferred:

```
var arr = [];
for(var i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
  arr.push(i);
}
arr[0]; // => 1
```

Answer (score 6):

This will do it:

```
for(var i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
    eval("variable_" + i + " = " + i + ";");
}
```

`eval` is basically evil, but for such purpose it's OK to use it. ([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197769/when-is-javascripts-eval-not-evil))

[Live test case](http://jsfiddle.net/U9HME/).

Comment: It's important to note that `eval` itself isn't evil. Misusing `eval` is evil. `eval` is actually a powerful tool for some situations (although not necessary for this one, IMO). See my answer.

Comment: @benekastah I agree, but looks like most JavaScript world class professional are totally against `eval` - probably because the risk of misusing it is greater than the gain. As for better alternative I also agree, but can't see any harm in having 100 variables so didn't advice against it.

Comment: I'd say 99.99% of the cases said variables would be global so `window['variable_'+n]` would work just fine

Comment: @ShadowWizard: I can see harm is having 100 variables. The only allowed number in computer science are 0, 1 and n+1. If you want to store 100 of something you really should be using an array.

Comment: @missingno as for `window` you might be right, anyhow I believe what the OP gave is just example and he won't store just numbers in there.

Comment: You are re-invoking the interpreter in a loop.  Performance-wise, that's pretty bad: http://jsperf.com/eval-vs-array

Answer (score 6):

You are better off using an array

```
var variable = [];
for (var i=1; i <= 100; i++) {
  variable[i] = i;
}
```

Later, you can access the values using variable[1], variable[2] etc.

Answer (score 3):

If it is like that why not to define array of the objects

```
var a = new Array();
for(i=0;i<100;i+=)
 a[i] = i;
```

Comment: Don't use `new Array()`. Its evil

Comment: @missingno - ok thanks for the info......its just to point op that you can better go for array rather than go for that eval approch

Comment: Don't worry, I know eval is even more evil

Answer (score 3):

Use an array:

```
var variable = [];

for(var i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
    variable[i] = i;
}
```

By way of analogy, you'd want to use an array instead of 100 variables for the same reason you'd want

```
<div class="variable"></div>
<div class="variable"></div>
<div class="variable"></div>
//and so on
```

instead of

```
<div id="variable_1"></div>
<div id="variable_2"></div>
<div id="variable_3"></div>
//and so on
<div id="variable_100"></div>
```

---

```
Invalid left-hand side in assignment
```

This error gets generated because `variable_ + i` is an expression.  The interpreter thinks you are trying to add two variables instead of concatenating a variable name and a string.  An expression cannot be on the left-hand side of an assignment operation.

Answer (score 3):

Why not using an array instead like this?

```
<script language="javascript">
var arrayVar = new Array();

for (var i=0; i<100; i++) {
    arrayVar["variable_" + i] = i;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Don't use `new Array()` its evil

Comment: Thanks for the advice @missingno, next time, I'll use a new missingno() instead

Comment: Using `new missingno()` will erase your Indigo League hall of fame records. Plain `[]` is less buggy.

Answer (score 2):

```
for(var i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
    window["variable_" + i] = i;
}

alert( variable_50 );

alert( variable_34 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're on a browser you can do:

`global[variable] = 'hello'`

`console.log(variable)` -> `hello`