# Programmatically set variable names by appending an ID parameter

Tags: javascript

Below is an example of my code

```
/// Control vars ///

/// Control var ID ///
var id=2;
///

/// Load Fields by ID ///
var name_s_+id=jQuery("#name_c_"+id).val();
///


alert("name_s_"+id);
```

I have an ID which can be, for example, any value in (1,4,5,3,2 ....... etc)

I would like to create references using the naming scheme `var name_s_(Load ID)`

How does JavaScript support such dynamic variable names, and how can I reference the value in my code to, for example, alert it's value:

```
alert("name_s_"+id);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Programmatically setting the name of a variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8525221/programmatically-setting-the-name-of-a-variable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an object.

```
var id=2;

var name_s = {};

name_s[id] = jQuery("#name_c_" + id).val();

alert(name_s[id]);
```

If your IDs are fairly consecutive and start at 0 (or even 1), you can use an array instead:

```
var name_s = [];
```

(and the rest is the same).

Comment: Fantastic , great , regards