# Select a variable/object by it's name from many available with Javascript

Tags: javascript, syntax

I have many objects (global):

```
let JohnA = {some data};
let GeorgeA = {some data};
...
```

Now I want to select an object by it's name in this context:

```
....
var randomselected = "John";
var result = obj.countries[key]['dataform'];
....
```

Here instead of obj. I need to have something like:

```
var result = randomselected+"A".countries[key]['dataform'];
```

So it works same as with:

```
var result = JohnA.countries[key]['dataform'];
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8525221/programmatically-setting-the-name-of-a-variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript won't give you a list of declared variables and their names, so what you're trying to do won't work with plain variables unless you use `eval` like in Majed's answer, but I don't recommend that—using `eval` is generally discouraged because depending on your code it can open you up to security vulnerabilities.

What you could do instead is store `JohnA` and `GeorgeA` as properties on an object like so:

```js
let names = {
  JohnA: { countries: ... },
  GeorgeA: { countries: ... } 
}
```

and then you can programmatically access those properties:

```js
let name = 'John';
names[name + 'A'].countries // ...
```

Comment: On the issue of eval:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197769/when-is-javascripts-eval-not-evil

Answer (score 1):

You can use `eval`. Here is a simple example:

```js
let JohnA = {name:"John"};
let p = "John";
let name = eval(`${p}A`).name;
console.log(name);
```